# Listview can't displayed the last item

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

This is the my current listivew:
 [image]

My problem is  i can't display my last item in the list. It's like getting cut by my phone.

Here is the xml code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="280dp"

        android:background="@drawable/dfcomment3"
        android:layout_weight="0.07">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="Add comment"
                android:id="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_marginTop="215dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="Update Post"
                android:id="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_marginTop="215dp" />
            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="Close This"
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_marginTop="215dp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="ID"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#994495"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="#994495"
            android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:text="Lastname"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:textColor="#994495"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/id"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/id"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:text="title"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#994495"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/name"
            android:layout_marginTop="190dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="descr"
            android:textSize="21dp"
            android:textColor="#994495"
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dept"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textColor="#994495"
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="tags"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textColor="#994495"
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="status"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#70CC86"
            android:id="@+id/textView18"
            android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="date"
            android:textColor="#994495"
            android:id="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="190dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As much as possible i want to stick with the listview because i'm not familiar with the recyclerview. if theres any way to fix this, i  would be glad.
Check the image for the reference of my problem.

There's actually 4 items in the list and i can only view 2 items.

Comment: You need to add your java code. Problem is not in XML.

Comment: Or maybe you want to say that you are getting the data in List View but can't show it due to less space on screen ??

Comment: @Swarnveer pardon me about my sentence, yes you are right.

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you xml to :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.07"--> Delete this
        >
      ....
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" -> Add this
        android:layout_height="0dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly there is problem with your XML as when you use weightsum and layout_weight then you need not give dimensions in height or width. 
This must be your XML.
Also I checked your XML there is some problem in you XML attributes too. Like you used "android:layout_below="@+id/id"" but in your xml there is no "id"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="100">
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/border"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dfcomment3"
    android:layout_weight="70">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Add comment"
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_marginTop="215dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Update Post"
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:layout_marginTop="215dp" />
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Close This"
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            android:layout_marginTop="215dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ID"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#994495"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="#994495"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:text="Lastname"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:textColor="#994495"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/id"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/id"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:text="title"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#994495"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="descr"
        android:textSize="21dp"
        android:textColor="#994495"
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dept"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="#994495"
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="tags"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColor="#994495"
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="status"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#70CC86"
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="date"
        android:textColor="#994495"
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:layout_height="0dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Add your java code if you are not getting 4 values into your ListView

Comment: And remember you need to correct your attribute's Id. Check for red underline

Comment: Accept the answer if it solved your problem or comment further if you need more help

Comment: can you help me with this:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44350892/adjust-layout-based-on-the-screen-size